# Pytorch - How to achieve higher accuracy with imdb review dataset using LSTM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to practice with LSTM and Pytorch. I took [IMDB movie review dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/imdb-movie-reviews-dataset/kernels) to predict whether the review is positive or negative. I use 80% of the dataset for my training, remove punctuations, use `GloVe` (with 200 dims) as an embedding layer.

Before training, I also exclude too short (reviews with length smaller than 50 symbols) and too long (reviews with longer than 1000 symbols) reviews.

For the `LSTM` layer I use `hidden dimension 256`, `num_layers 2` and `one directional` parameters with `0.5 dropout`. Afterwards, I have fully connected layer.
For the training I used nn.BCELoss function with Adam optimizer (`lr=0.001`).

Currently I get 85% validation accuracy with 98% training accuracy after 7 epochs. I did following steps for preventing overfitting and getting higher accuracy:

- used weight_decay for Adam optimizer,
- tried SGD (lr=0.1, 0.001) instead of Adam,
- tried to increase num_layers of LSTM,

In all of these cases model didn't learn at all, giving 50% of accuracy for both training and validation sets.

```py
class CustomLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, use_embed=False, embed=None, embedding_size=200, hidden_size=256,
                 num_lstm_layers=2, bidirectional=False, dropout=0.5, output_dims=2):
        super().__init__()

        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_lstm_layers = num_lstm_layers
        self.bidirectional = bidirectional
        self.dropout = dropout

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)
        if use_embed:
            self.embedding.weight.data.copy_(torch.from_numpy(embed))
#             self.embedding.requires_grad = False
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_size,
                           hidden_size=hidden_size,
                           num_layers=num_lstm_layers,
                           batch_first=True,
                           dropout=dropout,
                           bidirectional=bidirectional)
#         print('output dims value ', output_dims)
        self.drop_fc = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_dims)
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
```

I want to understand:

1. Why the model doesn't learn at all with that changes applied?
2. How to increase the accuracy?

Comment: Hello, I'm also doing a project with IMDb using rnn, I'm wondering if you can share some more detail about your model on the forward function? as my model's accuracy is stuck at 50% without setting bidirectional to true.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put attention after LSTM layers. I have tried it before with the same problem.

[BiLSTM with Attention Based
Sentiment Analysis](https://aclweb.org/anthology/S18-1040)

The other option, You can consider to use other architecture like CNN  combine with ensemble technique (it work great for me).

[Distinguish Positive and Negative Documents](https://github.com/andyngo95/SA_Positive_Negative_Comments/blob/master/Sentiment_Analysis_v2.ipynb)